# Running JSF pages by IntelliJ fails to work while HTML pages work correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsf-2

I'm started to learn `JSF`. I'm learning from a videotutorial that uses `Eclipse` but I'd like to use `IntelliJ`. I managed to do almost everything but I have encounter one problem. Simple HTML pages are shown correctly in my webrowser but JSF pages (i.e. `.xhtml`) are not, ie. my webbrowser shows a blank page, but this is exacly the same page that I have in Intellij (all tags etc. are there). I *guess* this is because JSF pages are sent to the browser as is (i.e. raw), and tags thats start with `h:` (e.g. `<h:head>`) and it fails to recognize those tags correctly. I'm using `Tomcat 8.5.20` (latest) as server. Here's my simple  JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>First JSF app</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Enter your name:</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="hello"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

As requested, my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**As per request**

JSF libraries seem to be available to Tomcat.
[image]

Thanks to @asgs I've found an error in Tomcat log. It reads as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

However, I have `javax.faces-2.2.1.jar` in lib folder.

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error beside the fact that the webrowser shows an empty page.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml and your project file system structure? Your jsf is being served without getting rendered to html because of a mis-configuration in your app, not intellij, I suspect.

Comment: Sure, I will do it right now.

Comment: don't you need to make the JSF lib available to your Tomcat container (assuming it's not already bundled)? Also, when you view source from the browser, what do you see? Are there any errors logged in the Browser console?